MapMyIndia crashes flutter app, as soon as it's opened
I am using mapmyIndia flutter package, as soon as I open the maps in my app it fetches the latitude and longitude it crashes my app, some relevant error lines:
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(32396): Exception in onDidFinishLoadingStyle
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(32396): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~aCzQH_voPlpcZjkm0Gqb0w==/com.example.haulfers_user_app-wubWe9W5eFkUcl35XXtVkA==/base.apk)
if you could tell me if there is a version error, I am not able to resolve
I tried adding different versions but nothing is working the app crashes everytime

Can you post relevant code part of the crash?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
